# Host key verification failed in google compute engine based mpich cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mpi, google-compute-engine, mpich

TLDR:

I have 2 `google compute engine` instances, I've installed `mpich` on both.
When I try to run a sample I get `Host key verification failed`.

Detailed version:

I've followed this tutorial in order to get this task done: http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/.

I have 2 `google compute engine` vms with `ubuntu 14.04` (the google cloud account is a trial one, btw). I've downloaded this version of mpich on both instances: `http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.3rc1
/mpich-3.3rc1.tar.gz` and I installed it using these steps:

```
./configure --disable-fortran
sudo make
sudo make install
```

This is the way the `/etc/hosts` file looks on the `master`-node:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
10.128.0.3 client
10.128.0.2 master
10.128.0.2 linux1.us-central1-c.c.ultimate-triode-161918.internal linux
1  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

And this is the way the `/etc/hosts` file looks on the `client`-node:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
10.128.0.2 master
10.128.0.3 client
10.128.0.3 linux2.us-central1-c.c.ultimate-triode-161918.internal linux
2  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

The rest of the steps involved adding an user named `mpiuser` on both nodes and configuring passwordless ssh authentication between the nodes. And configuring a `cloud` shared directory between nodes.

The configuration worked till this point. I've downloaded this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmodels/mpich/master/examples/cpi.c to `/home/mpiuser/cloud/mpi_sample.c`, compiled it this way:

```
mpicc -o mpi_sample mpi_sample.c
```

and issued this command on the master node while logged in as the `mpiuser`:

```
 mpirun -np 2 -hosts client,master ./mpi_sample
```

and I got this error:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

What's wrong? I've tried to troubleshoot this problem over more than 2 days but I can't get a valid solution.

[image]

Comment: This message implies that passwordless SSH does **not** work ! Assuming you are invoking `mpirun` from the `mpiuser` account on the `master` host, simply `ssh client` from there, and accept or fix the remote host key. You might have to do the same operation on the `client` host.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet How exactly would you fix/accept key on the remote host?

Comment: did you even try `ssh client` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes. I've tried to regenerate the key manually but I still get that error.

Comment: what does `ssh client` says ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/aHoAWcP

Comment: can you `ssh master` from `linux1` as `mpiuser` ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/FHESpSr

Comment: type `yes` and try again your `mpirun` command

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/T2jitMr

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IcCb3Ys

Comment: you went one step further ! unless the home directory of `mpiuser` is on a shared filesystem, you have to manually copy `mpi_sample` on `client`

Comment: it is actually mounted on the network https://imgur.com/a/sH26pOo

Comment: why do you `sudo mpirun ...` instead of `mpirun ...` ? from `linux2`, `ssh client` and `ssh master` (and accept the keys if needed)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet https://imgur.com/a/4KYX695

Comment: it looks like that though the SSH host keys are fine, you cannot SSH password less between hosts ... `ssh client true` and `ssh master true` should simply return when invoked from *both* hosts.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/J8agFNT

Comment: it seems 1 out of 4 ssh works password less, and this is what you need to fix before trying `mpirun`. fwiw, this strongly suggests `~mpiuser/.ssh` is not on a shared filesystem ... (and if it is not by design, you have to manually deploy all your user keys on all your hosts).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've copied the public rsa key manually from the master node to `./ssh` on client https://imgur.com/a/mJx1tUC but it still doesn't work

Comment: do 4 out of 4 ssh work passwordless ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Is there any workaround to get a working mpi version?

Comment: you can use a resource manager (such as SLURM) so MPI does not rely on SSH. That being said, you'd rather fix SSH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186131/discussion-between-cristid9-and-gilles-gouaillardet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
package-lock.json
```

in ".gcloudignore file".

And deploy it again.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my password less ssh wasn't configured properly. I've created 2 new instances and did the following things to get a working password less and thus get a working version of that sample. The following steps were execute on an `ubuntu server 18.04`.

First, by default, instances on google cloud have `PasswordAuthentication` setting turned off. In the **client** server do:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and change `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`. Then

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

Generate a `ssh` key from the **master** server with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user.mail@server.com"
```

Copy the generated `ssh` key from the **master** server to the **client**

```
ssh-copy-id client
```

Now you get a fully functional password less ssh from **master** to **client**. However `mpich` still failed.

The additional steps that I did was to copy the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, both on **master** and **client**. So execute this command from both servers:

```
sudo cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then make sure the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files from both the **client** and **server** have the following configurations:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

Restart the `ssh` service from both **client** and **master**

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

And that's it,  `mpich` works smoothly now.